# Multivariable Inverse

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $ x:R^2 → R^3$, $x(u, v) = (u + v, u − v, uv)$. Find its inverse.
I know how to find inverses of single variable functions. Can someone provide some guidance as to how to approach this? Please and thank you.

Comment: You are given three numbers which represent the sum, difference and product of two numbers, respectively. Can you recover the two numbers from those?

Comment: A function from $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ with $m\neq n$ will never be invertible (even not locally).

Comment: @Surb In this case it is in the sense that $x^{-1}(x(u,v))=(u,v)$.